# Snowflake Strategy for PITR and backup archival?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was curious on other's Snowflake backup archival/PITR strategy on how you keep your Snowflake database backups past the maximum 97 backup time (assumes Enterprise edition, 90 days for time-travel and 7 extra days for fail-safe) for a database's point-in-time-recovery (PITR)?

*97 days is a lot of time for PITR but problems are not always caught until its too late in my experiences thus the need for backups past the max 97 days.*

## Example Scenario

The RPO is 12 months for a business, my initial train of thought to meet this RPO is:

1. Setup a task to create a clone of the database on day 97 (via maximum restore time supported by Snowflake)
2. The clone is created and the snapshot of the previous 97 days ensures PITR capability for the database (as time-travel is now being overwritten)
3. Another 97 days pass, the previous clone of the database is backed up "physically" to an external storage location (AWS/Azure/GCP) to archive the backup. Once the database backup is archived, the previous clone is dropped and another clone of the database is created to backup the previous 97 days (like step 2).
4. Repeat the process to ensure PITR and business as usual in case of DR

I might not 100% understand how time-travel/fail-safe "resets" when it reaches its maximum age for a database but i if understand correctly how time-travel resets, I am curious on others thoughts and different methods on how this would be achieved?

Also if there is a current snowflake best practice for this type of backup archival/PITR strategy, I'd be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: If you clone a database that clone doesn’t include any of the time travel history of the source. So your approach doesn’t extend PITR beyond 97 days

Comment: That is true there isnt time-travel for the clone but creating the clone every 90 days will keep a snapshot of your data for PITR (not utilizing the the time-travel feature) you'd have to write your own sql DDL/DML to restore data from the quarterly clones

Comment: ** not a true PITR but the date the clone was created will give you a static view of the data at that point in time

Comment: @DuckDBAT55,  this is correct, the cloned object is stale data. The questions to ask SnowFlake: Is that possible use time travel - 1) on a cloned object from taken today, then I want to query the cloned object to retrieve data 10 days in past from today? 2) on a cloned object taken today and then Table B got modified, then I want to query the cloned object to retrieve data on Table A (not modified) 10 days in past from today? 3) on a cloned object taken today and then Table B got modified, then I want to query the cloned object to retrieve data on Table B (modified) 10 days in past from today?

Comment: If answers to the 3 questions listed above is "No, Time Travel cannot be used on the the CLONED object to restore data as it was on the original object before the cloned got created." Then The only way is to take a snapshot of an ORIGINAL object using Zero Copy Clone every day (365 days a year; similar to taking daily snapshot (files in S3) in Redshift). But there might be a limit to how many snapshots of ORIGINAL object could be taken over the time period. So If you not modify your clones(snapshots) then no additional storage cost incur.

Comment: To avoid modification on the Snowflake snapshots (cloned objects) restrict access to user who can modify and access them. And in case am undesired snapshot modification occurred then each clone has up to 90 days of Time Travel (customer controlled) and 7 days of disaster recovery (Snowflake Admin controlled); so you could roll them changes back.

Comment: And other way to daily backup your SnowFlake data is to copy it to S3 bucket or other blob storage - to use COPY INTO https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep 12 months of historical data and need to be able to restore data using the Point in Time Recovery  (PITR) approach,

then I see 2 alternatives, which actually can be implemented in parallel without affecting each other:

1. to take a snapshot of an ORIGINAL object using Zero Copy Clone every day (365 days a year; similar to taking daily a snapshot (files in S3) in Redshift). But there might be a limit to how many snapshots of ORIGINAL object could be taken over the time period (TBD in Question #2 above). So, in this case we would have 365 + 90 days of Time Travel (Customer controlled) + 7 days of Disaster recovery (Snowflake Admin controlled);
2. to backup daily SnowFlake data to S3 bucket - to use COPY INTO command.

I've confirmed with Snowflake You can backup the Original source as many times as you want using Zero Copy Clone. There is a soft limit of number of databases that can be created in an account, which is in the thousands.

Also note, Time Travel cannot be used on the CLONED object to restore data as it was on the original object before the cloned object was created. Though, you can use Time Travel on the CLONED object after it was created to keep tack of feature changes.